# How to save map to sdcard

Tags: android, android-emulator

In my application I need to save map to sdcard. I am able to create directory and file, but in that file nothing is saved.How to save the map which is displayed? Please help me to solve my issue...

```
         File myDir=new File("/sdcard/ma");
     myDir.mkdirs();
     Random generator = new Random();
     int n = 10000;
     n = generator.nextInt(n);
     String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
     File file = new File (myDir, fname);
     if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
     try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

            out.flush();
            out.close();

     } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
     }  

I added permissions in android manifest file 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: A screenshot can help you?